# Silverlight: Separator within listbox?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a listbox with several items in it. I would like to programmatically insert a separator bar into the list box. Is this possible?

MSDN speaks of a [Separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.separator.aspx) control, but Visual Studio doesn't recognize it when I try to instantiate one.

I'm using Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 2):

The Separator control you refer to is in WPF and not supported in Silverlight from what I can see in the documentation.

I would handle this via templates.  Set up your template with a representation of the item and a second representation of a separator and then bind the visibility of each to a an IsSeparator flag on your data object.

Then all you need to do is set create a dummy object with the IsSeparator flag set to true to get the new item in your list.

Answer (score 1):

see :
http://manfredlange.blogspot.com/2009/04/separator-for-menu-item-in-xaml-wpf.html

I use it in silverlight 4, I simply drag & drop from the toolbox and it added me a reference to the toolkit:

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
```

and I use it this way:

```
<toolkit:Separator Margin="15"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a fix similar to James. Adding a boolean field on to the TableModel that the listbox was being bound.

I had an extra requirement of data grouped by Types, which I left in the LINQ query below. If you don't need this you can use allData.Count in place of numDataTypes. My boolean was called IsLastItem and was populated with:

```
int numDataTypes = allData.Select(o => o.Type).Distinct().Count();
IEnumerable<TableModel> ByTypes = allData
              .GroupBy(o => o.Type)
              .Select((g, index) => new TableModel()
              {
                ...
                IsLastItem = index == (numDataTypes - 1),
              });
```

Then in the ListBox (or ItemsControl) I used a Boolean to Visibility converter (similar to the one posted here [Silverlight 4: how to switch control visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655210/silverlight-4-how-to-switch-control-visibility)):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ByTypes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                ...

                <!-- Seperator between list items -->
                <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Height="20" Visibility="{Binding IsLastItem, Converter={StaticResource VisibileWhenFalseConverter}}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```