# How to make Silverlight Dataform EditTemplate show controls based on checkbox state?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, ria

I want to use XAML for this with as little code-behind as possible. I have a DataForm with a custom Edit Template that looks like this:

---

[ X ] Checkbox 1

[ Control Panel ]

---

I want to display a set of controls below the "Checkbox 1" control (where the Control Panel is) IF Checkbox 1 IS checked, and if it's unchecked I want to display a different set of controls.

I am using Silverlight 4 (soon to use SL 5). Is there a Silverlight control holder that lets me "switch" which active panel is visible by setting an "ActivePanel" ID or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with MVVM you can just bind Visibility of your Grids to the same property that `CheckBox.IsChecked` is Binded to (of course  you must use right Converters).

Comment: I ended up using this method: http://www.rhyous.com/2011/02/22/binding-visibility-to-a-bool-value-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

Just have 2 separate panels. For eg.

```
<Grid x:Name="OnGrid" Visibility="Collapsed" />
<Grid x:Name="OffGrid" Visibility="Collapsed" />
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
```

Set the visibility of each in the code-behind event for unchecked and checked.

```
    private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OffGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        OnGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OffGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        OnGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

OR, you may use converters and do everything in xaml. For eg.

See this link: [Silverlight 4: how to switch control visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655210/silverlight-4-how-to-switch-control-visibility/3655356#3655356)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using code behind? Like can I use a {Binding} in the Visibility attribute and have the binding refer to the IsChecked value of the checkbox? The binding return value would have to be reversed for the second panel.

Comment: Yes you can. You need to write a booleantovisibility converter