# Change ToggleButton image when clicked Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, xaml, togglebutton

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change a ToggleButton image when clicked.  I have looked up countless examples and they are all outdated and no longer work. Or if they do I cannot get them to work. Does anyone have an up to date example I could look at or any suggestions?

I tried doing it in the code behind first. The example I found used a BitmapImage but this is not possible anymore as the BeginInit method cant be used due to security reasons.

Next I tried numerous style triggers but I get way to many compile errors even when they are directly copied and modified to fit the correct parameters. So I am stuck. I cant figure out how to use an EventTrigger to do it nor do any older examples seem to work. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What security reasons would that be?

Comment: I don't know. I searched for it via Google and there was a thread where they stated that loading images from a local machine causes security issues and Silverlight doesn't support it. If I try to go ahead and do it anyways it wont compile.

Comment: That does make sense but why are you trying to access images on the local machine in the first place?

Comment: I am making a custom media player. I want to be able to swap the play button to a pause button when it is clicked. However I cannot figure out how to do such a thing.

Comment: You could embedd the images in the application as resource, then there should be no access problem, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something like:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="b">
  <Image Src="myImage.png" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=b,Path=IsChecked,Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
  <Image Src="myOtherImage.png" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=b,Path=IsChecked,Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter,ConverterParameter=Invert}}"/>
</ToggleButton>
```

Where you have a boolean to visibility converter that can accept a parameter to invert the bool.

Edit:

You'll need to define a converter so that it can convert the `bool?` from the `IsChecked` property to a `Visibility` enum.  That's what all the binding code does. There is a basic implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655210/silverlight-4-how-to-switch-control-visibility) that will convert to `Visibility.Visible` when true and `Visibility.Collapsed` when false.  You need to add a check for the `parameter` so that it inverts the visibility when `Invert` is passed (to toggle between two images).

The other way to do this is to define images in the style and use the visual states for `Checked` and `Unchecked` to flip flop the images.  You can apply a style to multiple buttons but it's hard to vary the images per-button (what my solution does).

This is how you set up a Resource

### XAML

```
<!-- Place this in your window -->
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:NameSpace"

<!-- Place this above your root UI -->
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then use the converter here [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2008/10/27/binding-converters---visibilityconverter.aspx)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am very new to xaml but I tried to use your code and it gives multiple errors which I'm not sure how to fix. The first line says it is expecting a }. The second line says image does not support direct content. Any suggestions?

Comment: Missing a `}` on the end there, see my edit.  Read up on `ValueConverter` and how to use it in XAML.

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't have time to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ImageToggleButton and ImageToggleButtonSideBySide (if you want a Mac-style toggle [or 2-state radio could call it] button) from ImageButtons project of [ClipFlair](http://ClipFlair.codeplex.com) project codebase